# Elements change position depending on display type

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS and was wondering what could be the reason for my elements to change depending on the display that's viewing the page. On my 24" screen it looks good. But on my 15" laptop screen, there are elements that clip through the page.

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="">
        <h1>Registreer</h1>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="password" placeholder="wachtwoord" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="password" placeholder="herhaal wachtwoord" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <div class="custom_select">
                <select>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteer geslacht</option>
                    <option value="man">Man</option>
                    <option value="vrouw">Vrouw</option>
                    <option value="vrouw">Anders</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(230, 4, 4, 0.1);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
    margin-top: 285px; /* Hier is de toegevoegde regel om de wrapper naar beneden te brengen */
}

.wrapper:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .input-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px 0;
}



.input-box input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid rgba(177, 177, 177, 0.2);
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 45px 20px 20px;
}
.wrapper .input-box input::placeholder {
    
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
}

.input-box input:hover{
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}



.wrapper .remember-forgot{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    margin: -15px 0 15px;
}

.remember-forgot label input {
    accent-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.remember-forgot a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.remember-forgot a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}



.wrapper .btn{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.wrapper .register-link{
    font-size: 14.5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 15px;
}

.register-link p a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.register-link p a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.custom_select select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.2);
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

.custom_select select:hover{
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}
```

I've tried using meta links like:

```html
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
```

But with no visible changes.

Comment: that's because your code is not responsive. I suggest you watch some tutorials in YouTube about making a responsive webpage using CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a relative width for your wrapper class. If you use:

```
width: 70%;
```

instead of:

```
width: 500px;
```

The element will take 70% width from the parent element. If you use px as an unit it will always take 500px width. This can be a problem if the page is displayed, as in your fault, on a smaller screen.